# How can I set a variable to be at least a minimum value with C#

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
Current.Resources["CardSetIconWidth"]   = (width-30)/260 * 160;
```

I would like to ensure that `Current.Resources["CardSetIconWidth"]` is always at least a minimum of 160.

Is there an easy way that I can do this?

Comment: use conditionals.

Comment: `= Math.Max((width-30)/260 * 160, 160);`

Comment: Well, you'd usually use a setter for that. In that case I'd suggest using a function to set the value or use ```Math.Max```.

Comment: Why not just a simple if statement if Current.Resources["CardSetIconWidth"] >160 but of course if its a string u will need to convert it to an int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Current.Resources["CardSetIconWidth"] = Math.Max((width - 30) / 260 * 160, 160);
```

Answer (score 0):

After the assignment, you could do

```
if (Current.Resources["CardSetIconWidth"]<160) Current.Resources["CardSetIconWidth"]=160;
```

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use @rfmodulator answer into the indexer of a class:

```
public class SafeValues
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string, int> _dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    public int this[string key]
    {
        get { return _dict[key]; } // you can also choose to use Math.Min 
                                   // in the getter to keep the original values in the underlying dictionary
                                   // for debug purposes

        set { _dict[key] = Math.Max(value, 160); }
    }
}
```

So you can use it like

```
var Resources = new SafeValues(); // you can easily set a parameter for the min value in the constructor if you want
Resources["CardSetIconWidth"] = (width-30)/260 * 160;
```